# Modify xml file with a dataset and child relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to modify an existing XML-File.
I used a DataSet to load the XML File with the ReadXml method.

I then displayed the relevant entries via the GetChildRows method.

I  want to change/add/delete those ChildRows:

How can I accomplish this?

Below is the xml before edit

```
<einginedesign>
    <object om_id="111" objname="DelivaryInfo">
         <objprop prop_id="1">
            <prop_name>OrderRef</prop_name>
             <prop_desc>Order Reference</prop_desc>
             <prop_dtype>varchar</prop_dtype>
         </objprop>
    </object>
</einginedesign>
```

after i editing in the dataset and write to xml file.
the new added (child rows) are out of object.

```
<einginedesign>
    <object om_id="111" objname="DelivaryInfo">
         <objprop prop_id="1">
            <prop_name>OrderRef</prop_name>
             <prop_desc>Order Reference</prop_desc>
             <prop_dtype>varchar</prop_dtype>
         </objprop>
    </object>
     <objprop prop_id="2">
        <prop_name>TransNo</prop_name>
        <prop_desc>Transaction number</prop_desc>
        <prop_dtype>Numeric</prop_dtype>
     </objprop>
</einginedesign>
```

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the data relation when reading it from the xml schema. Have a look at the below link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s(v=VS.100).aspx, Also try using the DataSet.ReadXml(dsName,XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the below example, in order for it to be a child you will need to set the parent row, the below code xml will give the expected output:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("XMLFile1.xml", XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
ds.Tables[1].Rows.Add(new string[] {"0","0","0","0"});
ds.Tables[1].Rows[1].SetParentRow(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]);
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["prop_id"] = 1;
ds.WriteXml("xmlfile2.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);


<einginedesign>
<object om_id="111" objname="DelivaryInfo">
<objprop prop_id="1">
  <prop_name>OrderRef</prop_name>
  <prop_desc>Order Reference</prop_desc>
  <prop_dtype>varchar</prop_dtype>
</objprop>
<objprop prop_id="0">
  <prop_name>0</prop_name>
  <prop_desc>0</prop_desc>
  <prop_dtype>0</prop_dtype>
</objprop>
```

This is very basic and you would obviously have to search for the correct parent row etc.